# VIM svn tortoise integration: how to commit current buffer only?

Tags: svn, vim, tortoisesvn

The code below comes from [a vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Call_TortoiseSVN_commands_from_within_Vim).  It uses tortoise to commit all open buffers.

If there is a buffer open that is not in a repo it will tortoise will error out.

What is the version of this code that only commits the current buffer?
Also, vim should write the buffer before calling tortoise.

```
func! CommitSVNAll()
    let buflist = []
    for b in range(1, bufnr('$'))
        if buflisted(b) && filereadable(bufname(b))
            call add(buflist, fnamemodify(bufname(b), ':p'))
        endif
    endfor
    let files = join(buflist, '*')
    if files != ''
        silent exec '!start "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:commit /path:"'.files.'" /closeonend:4'
    else
        call confirm('No files loaded')
    endif
endfunc
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not about others doing the work for you. What have you tried, where are you struggling?

Comment: Sorry, I have zero experience with scripting in vim and didn't want to learn it for this task.  If the question is off topic, close it. Just looking for support.  I could rephrase the question to "How do you commit the current buffer in VIM with tortoise, I have tried _this_ code, but it doesn't work because.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give this a try, not tested:

```
func! CommitSVNAll()
    let files = fnamemodify(bufname('%'), ':p')
    if files != ''
        silent exec '!start "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:commit /path:"'.files.'" /closeonend:4'
    else
        call confirm('No files loaded')
    endif
endfunc
```

basically, I just set the `files` with current buffer name. No experience with tortoiseSVN, you have to test on your own.